# Вывод строк с чередующимися значениями

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день, всем. Есть таблица из трех столбцов, в одной из них содержатся значения (0,1) в форме: **0 1 0 1** 1 1 **0** 0 **1** Есть ли способ, которым можно вывести строки по чередующимся значениям в данном столбце? В данном примере **0 1 0 1 0 1** При попытке использования inner join'a выдает значения 0 1 0 1 1 0, поэтому чередование не получается сделать. Буду рад любым подсказкам.

Comment: Можно ли увидеть какие у вас еще есть столбцы в базе (может быть ИД или иная колонка, которую можно будет использовать для сортировки), пример исходных данных и желаемый результат в виде пары строк?

Comment: + Если например будет 0 больше чем 1 - то что делать? выводить их в конце или не выводить вовсе?

Comment: @PASE7 достаточно было уточнить предыдущий вопрос, а не задавать новый.

Comment: @PashaPash думал туда никто уже не зайдет :)

Comment: @PASE7 надо было просто отредактировать вопрос, добавив в него конкретный пример и ожидаемый результат. редактирование поднимает вопрос вверх. а так у вас сейчас есть два полурешения, причем я не понимаю, чем вас не устроило первое, и как вы собираетесь применить к своим данных второе

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Нумеруете отдельно 1 и отдельно 0. Потом к номеру для 1чек прибавляете 0,5 и сортируете по номеру )

В общем вот такая штука получается:

```
select id , bit 
from
(
select id, bit, case when bit=0 then 0 else 0.5 end + row_number() over (partition by bit order by id) r_n 
from tmp 
) a 
order by r_n
```

Посмотреть как работает - можно тут [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/43101/1)